# How do I make the entire div clickable using plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, clickable

I don't need to write this in jQuery but I'm not versed enough in plain javascript to figure it out. Chris Coyier wrote a [nice explanation of what I'm talking about here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/).

The reason I want to convert it is because I don't need to include an entire jQuery library for this one piece of code. I can save that extra request by using plain old javascript.

This is the example code that I want to convert:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".featured").click(function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
    });
});
```

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll("div.feature").click(function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a").setAttribute("href"); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

One thing which isn't correct in this, as far as I know, are the `querySelectorAll`, which is looking for just a div element, right? The other thing is the `$(this)`, which I don't know how to translate into plain javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select with [this.querySelectorAll(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll):

IE8:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // get all dom elements with class "feature"
    var aFeatures = document.querySelectorAll(".feature");
    // for each selected element
    for (var i = 0; i < aFeatures.length; i++) {
        // add click handler
        aFeatures[i].onclick = function() {
            // get href of first anchor in element and change location
            window.location = this.querySelectorAll("a")[0].href;
            return false;
        };
    }
};
```

IE9 and other current browser:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // get all dom elements with class "feature"
    var aFeatures = document.querySelectorAll(".feature");
    // for each selected element
    for (var i = 0; i < aFeatures.length; i++) {
        // add click handler
        aFeatures[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            // get href of first anchor in element and change location
            window.location = this.querySelectorAll("a")[0].href;
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

=== UPDATE ===

For IE7 support you should add following (untested) script before (also see [here](https://gist.github.com/868532)):

```
(function(d){d=document,a=d.styleSheets[0]||d.createStyleSheet();d.querySelectorAll=function(e){a.addRule(e,'f:b');for(var l=d.all,b=0,c=[],f=l.length;b<f;b++)l[b].currentStyle.f&&c.push(l[b]);a.removeRule(0);return c}})()
```

It is possible that it only supports `document.querySelectorAll` not `element.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Is there a way to add IE7 support using javascript alone? Otherwise, I'll have to see if I can get the client live with IE7 functioning differently.

Comment: btw, I tested it and the IE8 version works for all browsers too. But it's great that you included both methods considering some people will drop support for IE8 in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming...

- you know the browser support for [`querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryse) and yet you still use it
- that `addEventListener` only works for standards compliant browsers

I believe you meant:

```
//get all a's inside divs that have class "featured"
var feat = document.querySelectorAll("div.featured a"),
    featlen = feat.length,
    i;

//loop through each
for(i=0;i<featlen;++i){
    //add listeners to each
    feat[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        window.location = this.href;
    },false);
}
```

---

Or you can have the `<div>` wrapped in `<a>`. No JS required. It's perfectly valid HTML and browsers do work as intended despite the rule that inline elements should not contain block elements. Just make sure to have `display:block` on `<a>` as well as adjust its size.

```
<a href="location">
    <div> content </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Oh no, querySelectorAll isn't supported by IE7. Darn. Is there a way around that problem? I also find it interesting that it's not as easy as translating the original jQuery into javascript as it is written.